# Using contractions to solve linear system of equations

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, fixed-point-theorems, contraction-operator

Consider the following system of equations in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$y = Cx +b$,

where $C$ is an $n\times n$ matrix with generic element $(c_{j,k})$. This matrix C satisfies $\sum_{k=1}^{n} |c_{j,k}| <1$, for any $j$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a given constant vector.

I'm asked to show that there's a solution for this system in the form

$x = Cx +b$.

This seems like an exercise about contractions and finding a fixed point. Here's my work:

Let $T(x) = Cx + b$. If we establish that $T$ is a contraction, then we have our result, because it's defined over a complete domain.

So: \begin{gather}
\| T(x) - T(y)\| =\|C(x-y)\| =
\sqrt{\sum_{j}(\sum_{k}|c_{j,k}|\left(x_{k} - y_{k}\right))^2} \leq 
\|x-y\|\sqrt{\sum_{j}\sum_{k}c_{j,k}^2}
\end{gather}

Sure, I can invert limits and use that the sum in $j$, for each $k$ will be less than $1$. My problem is that all upper bounds I can find for this depend on $n$, or $\sqrt{n}$ to be precise and, hence, I can't affirm that I have a contraction. What am I missing here?

Comment: $C$ is a contraction $\iff$ all its eigenvalues have a module (i.e., absolute value) <1. Your condition seems to be a sufficient condition for that.

Comment: Right, but how does this condition imply that? Is this an immediate result from Linear Algebra?

Comment: Yes, it suffices to diagonalize the matrix (in case it is diagonalisable): the $n$th power of the diagonalized version is $diag(\lambda_1^n,... \lambda_k^n)$ which converges to $0$ iff all $\lambda_i$s have a module $<1$.

Comment: Cool, this is clear. My questions is how the condition given by the exercise implies the condition you mentioned about the eigenvalues.